# Where do javascript files go in a Maven webapp archetype?

Tags: java, javascript, maven, spring-mvc

I have a java Spring MVC web app with the following directory structure :

```
src/
    main/
        java/
        resources/
        webapp/
```

In my webapp folder, I have a number of html files with javascript scripts. I don't want to have the javascript embedded in the html, I want it externalized. Where am I supposed to put the javascript files in the above file structure and what configuration do I have to add to my pom.xml and/or servlet-context.xml (spring) files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after reading the above answers and some other SO posts I have come to two solutions:

I'm using Spring MVC and my `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to root `/`. This means that any request for anything will go through it, but I have no controllers to serve resource files. What you can do is map the `DispatcherServlet` to something like `/app/*`. Then all regular urls like

`http:\\localhost:8080\ContextRoot\users`

will become accessible at

`http:\\localhost:8080\ContextRoot\app\users`.

You can then go to

`http:\\localhost:8080\ContextRoot\static\js\file.js`

and you'll be served the resource file by Apache server (or whatever you are using).

The guys at Spring probably saw this as an issue and made their own solution with `DispatcherServlet` still mapped at `/`. In your `servlet.xml` file you have to add

`<mvc:resources location = "/static/" mapping = "/static/**" />`

with your folder `static` being under folder `webapp`. This tag tells Spring MVC to have a special handler for anything going to `/static/`. You also need

`<mvc:annotation-driven>`

otherwise your Controllers handler methods will get mixed up with the handler from the previous tag and nothing will work (at least it didn't for me).

I tried both of these and they both worked but I went for the second one because my anchors in my views were mapped to root and I didn't feel like going to fix them all. Make your links relative, people!

Answer (score 1):

The common way is to put them under newly created static directory

```
webapp/static/js
```

and refer it with `/webcontext/static/js/somefile.js`

Comment: should be `<script src="/yourappwebcontext/static/js/someFile.js"/>`

Comment: should work, did you republish with js files ? can you see it exploded in your web directory from where server is serving ?

Comment: it depends how you deploy it, static dir should be directly under webapp

Comment: then may be server is serving from different place

Answer (score 0):

I think tath after you have created a normal Maven project you have only to create a new folder (by STS\Eclipse) like:

```
webapp/static/js
```

because javascript is not handled by Maven (you use Maven to adding new Java dependencies and compile it...Javascript are runtime script that are in your view code and there are not compiled code)

You can create a folder like this because are static stuff more like ald other things like jpg immage used in your application, .properties file...is thing that you have and that you use in your view but that you not handled by Maven.

Ah...probabily to work well you have to add this new folder in the classpath of your project.
In STS\Eclipse: right click on the name of your project --->  Properties ---> Java Build Path ---> tab Source  ---> click on Folders ---> and add the new folder that you have created

Comment: added details about classpath

Comment: mmm I think that in the classpath you have to put the directory that contains ALL the javascript file...